# D8 alter hook sequence

Tags: 8, hooks

I was wondering if using `hook_module_implements_alter()` is a good practice in D8 also to alter the order of execution of hooks?

I came to hear that it is suggested to do this with `events` that was introduced in D8 which will be a better way, but I could not find any reference that says not to use `hook_module_implements_alter()` in D8. [One such ref.](https://x-team.com/blog/changing-the-order-of-hooks-in-drupal/)

If using `events` is advised, can someone put up a small example as to how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if using hook_module_implements_alter() is a good practice in D8 also to alter the order of execution of hooks?

Yes it is - in fact it's the *only* way to alter the order of hook execution.

Events are something different. Their execution order is set in the implementation of each handler, and can't be affected by any hook.

Comment: "Yes it is - in fact it's the only way to alter the order of hook execution.". There's a second way and that's the module weight, which is the default execution order of hooks (weight, then alphabetically). But hook_module_implements_alter() is more flexible